# Type mismatch inferred type is Unit but Void was expected

Tags: kotlin

A kotlin method with a string and a listener (similar to closure in swift) parameters.

```
fun testA(str: String, listner: (lstr: String) -> Void) {

}
```

Calling it like this this.

```
testA("hello") { lstr ->
    print(lstr)
}
```

> Error: Type mismatch inferred type is Unit but Void was expected

What's Unit?? Return type of the closure is `Void`. Read lot of other questions but could find what's going on here with this simple method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to **Kotlin documentation** Unit type corresponds to the void type in Java. So the correct function without returning value in Kotlin is

```
fun hello(name: String): Unit {
    println("Hello $name")
}
```

Or use nothing

```
fun hello(name: String) {
    println("Hello $name")
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you *do* need `Void` (it's rarely useful, but could be when interoperating with Java code), you need to return `null` because `Void` is defined to have no instances (in contrast to Scala/Kotlin `Unit`, which has exactly one):

```
fun testA(str: String, listner: java.util.function.Function<String, Void?>) {
...
}

testA(("hello") { lstr ->
    print(lstr)
    null
}
```

Comment: `null` at the last line?? or `return null` ??

Comment: "We can explicitly return a value from the lambda using the qualified return syntax. Otherwise, the value of the last expression is implicitly returned." https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin uses `Unit` for methods which return nothing instead of `Void`. It should work

```
fun testA(str: String, listner: (lstr: String) -> Unit) {

}
```